# Why can't I copy a file to a location using an environment variable?

Tags: vbscript, outlook, copying, gpo

I have this code that copies outlook PST files, and when used with the full location file path it runs perfectly fine. I've added a method to run %UserProfile% in the first line as this needs to be run in a domain context from GPO and doing it individually is non-feasible. This runs and closes outlook and reopens it at the appropriate time except one thing is amiss.

It is no longer copying the appropriate files. I echoed the initial `%userprofile%` sections and it is reading the correctly as `"drive letter"\users\userprofile`. I'm not sure where this is breaking or how to identify it.

```
'===================BEGIN MODIFY====================================
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
userProfilePath = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%")

'Set the amount of pst-files you want to copy. Start counting at 0!
ReDim pst(1)

'Define the location of each pst-file to backup. Increase the counter!
pst(0) = "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\PST\Outlook Data File - mike.pst"
pst(1) = "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\PST\Archive.pst"

'Define your backup location
BackupPath = "%UserProfile%\Documents\Outlook Backups\"

'Keep old backups? TRUE/FALSE
KeepHistory = FALSE

'Maximum time in milliseconds for Outlook to close on its own
delay = 30000 'It is not recommended to set this below 8000

'Start Outlook again afterwards? TRUE/FALSE
start = TRUE

'===================STOP MODIFY====================================

'Close Outlook
Call CloseOutlook(delay)

'Outlook is closed, so we can start the backup
Call BackupPST(pst, BackupPath, KeepHistory)

'Open Outlook again when desired.
If start = TRUE Then
  Call OpenOutlook()
End If


Sub CloseOutlook(delay)
  strComputer = "."
  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
  & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

  'If Outlook is running, let it quit on its own.
  For Each Process in objWMIService.InstancesOf("Win32_Process")
    If StrComp(Process.Name,"OUTLOOK.EXE",vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
      Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
      objOutlook.Quit
      WScript.Sleep delay
      Exit For
    End If
  Next

  'Make sure Outlook is closed and otherwise force it.
  Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
  ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'Outlook.exe'")
  For Each objProcess in colProcessList
    objProcess.Terminate()
  Next
  Set objWMIService = Nothing
  Set objOutlook = Nothing
  set colProcessList = Nothing
End Sub


Sub BackupPST(pst, BackupPath, KeepHistory)
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  If KeepHistory = True Then
    ArchiveFolder = Year(Now) & "-" & Month(Now) & "-" & Day(Now)
    BackupPath = BackupPath & ArchiveFolder & "\"
  End If

  For Each pstPath in pst
    If fso.FileExists(pstPath) Then
      fso.CopyFile pstPath, BackupPath, True
    End If
  Next
  Set fso = Nothing
End Sub


Sub OpenOutlook()
  Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  objShell.Run "Outlook.exe"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declared `userProfilePath = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%")`, you put the path of %UserProfile% in the variable named `userProfilePath`, but afterward you don't use this variable. That's a problem, because a few lines down, what you end up doing is declaring `pst(#)` with `%userprofile%` as a string, which doesn't work.

**In other words, the %UserProfile% environment path/string needs to be expanded *before* being used as a path**.

Your code would work if you used the `userProfilePath` variable you declared:

```
'Define the location of each pst-file to backup. Increase the counter!
pst(0) = userProfilePath+"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\PST\Outlook Data File - mike.pst"
pst(1) = userProfilePath+"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\PST\Archive.pst"

'Define your backup location
BackupPath = userProfilePath"\Documents\Outlook Backups\"
```

instead of

```
'Define the location of each pst-file to backup. Increase the counter!
pst(0) = "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\PST\Outlook Data File - mike.pst"
pst(1) = "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\PST\Archive.pst"

'Define your backup location
BackupPath = "%UserProfile%\Documents\Outlook Backups\"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So obviously %Userprofile% was working in the context it knew it was drive\users\userprofile   any reason that one works better than the other? Also, missing a "+" at the end of the backup location. It will not let me mark your answer up as i have a low reputation but it is the answer!!!! Thanks!!

Comment: %UserProfile% is not interpreted outside of the command line interpreter (cmd.exe). In programs other than cmd shells, you have to get the value of the environement var (like you did) and then use it in replacement of the shell variable.